# Couldn't open python .exe application

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller

I created a simple face detection app using `pyqt5` and `opencv 3`. I used anaconda 3.6 and anaconda command prompts and used pyinstaller to create the .exe file.

*After running pyinstaller, the .py file converted to .exe file, and then it's no longer running.*

Whenever it's clicked on a command prompt it shows an error. I have attached the image.

I also tried cx_freeze and with that the command prompt pops up and goes away again within a millisecond. There I could see some numpy import error something, which I couldn't make an image of.

For everything I used anaconda cmd prompt and python from anaconda is used.

Please help me with a solution

[image: This one is showing now]

Comment: You created an application and it crashes on startup? OK, what changes did you make since the last time it did not crash on startup?

Comment: @zvone  Sorry, when I compiled the program, the GUI run. After with pyinstaller, the .Py file converted to .exe file, then it's not running

Comment: I added that information to the question for you ;)

Comment: Can you please try running the application from the command prompt and add the error output to your question as an edit?

Comment: @apogalacticon , I have added one more cmd prompt error image showing from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, import error no module named PyQt5. But I successfully executed the program and run the gui window and I detected my face on it.

Comment: @AshiqKS check my answer below on explicitly adding PyQt5 modules.

Comment: "Whenever it's clicked on a command prompt it shows an error. I have attached the image." You don't click on files in a command prompt. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is failing to launch because it cannot import the PyQt5 modules. You may add PyQt5 (or each of the PyQt5 modules that you are using) to the `hiddenimports` list in the .spec file that was generated after you first bundled this application with PyInstaller, and then regenerating the executable. Alternatively, you could explicitly add PyQt5 to your .py file by adding `import PyQt5` before any other PyQt5-related imported

Comment: Dear @apogalacticon , I tried to add import PyQt5 before any other PyQt5-related imported, but same result, and I don't know how to add PyQt5 modules in the .spec file.

Comment: @AshiqKS - to add modules to the .spec file: Once you run PyInstaller, a .spec file will be generated in the directory containing your .py file. You can open this .spec file and add modules to the list named `hiddenimports`. For example: `hiddenimports = ['PyQt5.QtCore', 'PyQt5.QtWidgets', 'any_other_modules']`. Once you've updated your .spec file, run the PyInstaller command again.

Answer (score 0):

After launching your .exe file created with PyInstaller, you are shown the following error:

```
Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-8
```

This error is reported on the [PyInstaller GitHub issues](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3146) page as well.

If you run PyInstaller with the `--debug` flag and then launch your application, do you see errors in your log file that resemble [this](https://gist.github.com/NulAsh/8c6fbf978a67561aa1a4bda2c36bb249)? Specifically, the following error may be near the beginning of the log file:

```
 File "c:\program files\python36\lib\re.py", line 142, in <module>
  class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
784 DEBUG: collect_submodules - Found submodules: {'encodings'}
```

This may be caused by an incompatible module (enum) overwriting the standard library. In this case, the recommended fix is to remove the enum34 package (`pip uninstall enum34`)

Comment: Dear @apogalaction , i did the pyinstaller --debug, but after that dist folder became empty. Also, enum34 is not installed, I checked. This above said error is not shown up.

Comment: Thanks for checking. After your recent update to your question, I no longer believe that this is the solution.

Comment: Dear @apogalaction, error was corrected but then the system codec error started showing up. I corrected that with uninstalling enum34. Thanks for help. App started running, but still it is not standalone as it needs face classifier xml file and .ui designer file in the same folder location to run. Do you have any suggestions as I want it to run on other windows systems too.

Comment: Hi @AshiqKS glad that I could help solve this problem. There are a few things that could be causing this issue. Could you please start a new question and post your error output and .spec file contents? That might help me find a solution for you. At the very least, you should add these external files to the `datas` list in the .spec file.